# Bootstrap 3 and IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, respond.js

I know this has been posted a few times, but I think my error is different than others.

I'm having the familiar problem of IE 7-9 showing my site as the mobile version but full width. The problems seems to lie with the respond.min.js file, although this could be because there is something wrong elsewhere.

Here is my header code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/odp.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Works fine in Chrome, etc but when running in IE8 I get a console error...

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 1 Jul 2014 09:18:50 UTC


Message: Access is denied.

Line: 5
Char: 858
Code: 0
URI: file:///(path deleted) js/vendor/respond.min.js
```

I have tried a couple of versions from different places - the file is in a folder at the same level as the web page - the path is definitely not a problem.

Can anyone help with this please?

DS

Answer (score 3):

It says on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

that the respond.js should not be called with file:///

> Respond.js and file://
>
> Due to browser security rules, Respond.js doesn't work with pages
>   viewed via the file:// protocol (like when opening a local HTML file).
>   To test responsive features in IE8, view your pages over HTTP(S). See
>   the Respond.js docs for details.

Also relative paths are different when including these files. I had to enter them with `./js` while all others are imported as `/js`

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the page must be on a server. Not just a file on a computer. I need to host this on localhost or on a web server to accommodate the AJAX call.

DS